# Как подавить срабатывание комбинаций клавиш браузера и Jupyter Lab, когда работаешь в терминале последнего?

Tags: консоль, jupyter-lab

Я хотел бы попробовать использовать терминал **Jupyter Lab** как основной для управления кластером. Но возникли проблемы с использованием стандартных консольных комбинаций, например, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> для удаления частей команды или <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> для управления `tmux`ом. К сожалению, я не смог отыскать никакого подходящего решения. Единственное, что как-то работает, это проставление `null` для всех комбинаций **Jupyter** в `json`-файле настроек, но это не подходит для практического использования.